# Operaciones aritméticas en Trigger MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber que tengo mal en este código, necesito actualizar un campo saldo con un trigger después de insertar un pago en una columna en diferentes tablas.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Saldo` AFTER INSERT ON `InfoPago` FOR EACH ROW  
UPDATE PedidoMatriz SET SaldoPorPagar=(PedidoMatriz.TotalDelPedido - InfoPago.CantidadPagada) 
WHERE PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz=NEW.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz
```

Comment: "tengo mal en este código" nada.. se ve muy lindo.. tenes algun error con el cual trabajar? asi como esta, no estaria nada mal.. no hace lo que tiene que hacer o que?

Comment: Me da error creo que es por la falta de relación de pedidomatriz, por así decirlo se puede tomar esté campo en el update ? creería que se tiene que crear una relación tipo inner join

Comment: te da error.. que error??? usa el boton [edit] y completa tu pregunta.. no estamos en tu cabeza, no conocemos tu base de datos, no vemos que pasa con la ejecucion de tu codigo... necesitamos una pregunta completa para poder ayudarte....

Comment: Amigo la pregunta es sencilla como hago para restar un campo de una tabla con otro campo de otra tabla!

Comment: exacatamente como lo haces.. siempre y cuando las dos tablas esten en el query.. que no es tu caso ;)

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa: *necesito actualizar un campo saldo con un trigger después de insertar un pago en una columna en **diferentes tablas***. ¿Hablas de insertar un valor en varias tablas y también lanzar un TRIGGER? ¿Por qué habría que insertar el mismo dato en dos tablas? Luego, si dices que da error, debes agregar a la pregunta el mensaje de error pulsando en [edit]. Analizando la consulta al menos esto es sospechoso: `NEW.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz` ¿Esa es una columna de `InfoPago`?  Es que como no vemos tu contexto, tenemos que adivinar, haciendo un esfuerzo.

Comment: Por si alguien lo necesita, solucione con esto : CREATE TRIGGER `Saldo` AFTER INSERT ON `InfoPago` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE PedidoMatriz INNER JOIN InfoPago ON InfoPago.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz = PedidoMatriz.idPedidoMatriz SET SaldoPorPagar=(PedidoMatriz.TotalDelPedido - InfoPago.CantidadPagada) WHERE InfoPago.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz=NEW.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien lo necesita, solucione con esto :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Saldo` AFTER INSERT ON `InfoPago` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE 
PedidoMatriz INNER JOIN InfoPago ON InfoPago.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz = 
PedidoMatriz.idPedidoMatriz SET SaldoPorPagar=(PedidoMatriz.TotalDelPedido - 
InfoPago.CantidadPagada) WHERE 
InfoPago.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz=NEW.PedidoMatriz_idPedidoMatriz
```